# How many numbers can be divided by $k$ in $1, 2, \text{...}, n$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

How many numbers can be divided by $k$ in $1, 2, \text{...}, n$?

$k=1$, there are $n$ numbers.

$k=2$,  there are$\left[\frac{n}{2}\right]$

$k=3$, there are $\left[\frac{n}{3}\right]$

$k=k$, there are $\left[\frac{n}{k}\right]$ ?

Seems right, how to prove?

$n\leq k\left[\frac{n}{k}\right]\leq n+1$？                                                                                                          so? obvious? proved?

Comment: $q\cdot k \leqslant n \iff q \leqslant \left\lfloor \frac{n}{k}\right\rfloor$.

Comment: Don't count the numbers, count the quotients.

Answer (score 1):

Numbers divisible by $k$ are $k,2k,3k,...,rk$. Let $rk$ be the greatest number divisible by $k$ in the set $\{1,2,3,...,n\}$

Then, $rk\leq n\implies r\leq \dfrac{n}{k}$. Since $r\in \Bbb Z\implies r=\lfloor\frac{n}{k}\rfloor$ as $r$ is the greatest integer $\leq \frac{n}{k}$